# Genealogytree extra edges doesn't follow correct path.

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I'm building a family tree using the `genealogytree`package, and I have bumped into a small problem. Perhaps this is a bug, or there is a workaround.

The grandfather of c3 had three wives. c3 is a descendant of the child (c1) of the third wife (bb1). I want to draw a path connecting the great grandfather (a1) to c3.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}[
template=formal graph,
extra edges prepend for families={
x={famA}{a1}{b1},
x={famB}{b1}{c1}, 
x={famC}{c1}{c3},
}{
foreground={red!25!yellow,line width=5pt},no background}
]
child[id=famA]{%
   g[id=a1]{a1}
   p[id=a2]{a2}
   child[id=famB]{%
      g[id=b1]{b1}
      p[id=b2]{b2}
      c[id=b3]{b3}
      union[id=famBa]{%
         p[id=ba1]{ba1}
         c[id=ba2]{ba2}
      }
      union[id=famBb]{%
         p[id=bb1]{bb1}
         child[id=famC]{%
            g[id=c1]{c1}
            p[id=c2]{c2}
            c[id=c3]{c3}
         }
      }
   }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is along the path `x={famB}{b1}{c1}`, the yellow line connects to c1 along the wrong path. Is there a way to fix this, or is it a bug?

Comment: I've abused the comment features of the site to ping the package author. I have no idea if this is a bug, a limitation or a feature :(.

Comment: The fix is to use `x={famB}{b1}{c1}` as @pst wrote. But, maybe, rearranging like @cfr did is also an alternative for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you simply mean `x={famBb}{b1}{c1}` instead of `x={famB}{b1}{c1}`, since that is the union with c1? (The documentation for extra edges says that parents and children in the construction "do not necessarily have to be *real* members of the current family", so you got a result anyway.)

Then you get

[image]

Comment: You were minutes faster than me to give this answer :-) I agree that `famBb` is the correct family to highlight.

Comment: Excellent! The documentation for Genealogytree is quite precise, but not always clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but it might be of interest as a workaround, depending on the details of your situation. In any case, it is too long for a comment.

It seems that the path followed corresponds to the primary partner, so to speak. Hence, if you can alter these relationships, you can highlight the relevant relationships.

For example:

[image: corrected relationships]

As I say, I have no idea whether this is of any help at all. Hopefully, the package author will see find his way to your post and provide a satisfactory solution. But I thought it worth posting this in case it was of some use in the meantime.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  [
    template=formal graph,
    extra edges prepend for families={
      x={famA}{a1}{b1},
      x={famB}{b1}{c1},
      x={famC}{c1}{c3},
    }{
      foreground={red!25!yellow,line width=5pt},no background
    }
  ]
  child[id=famA]{%
    g[id=a1]{a1}
    p[id=a2]{a2}
    child[id=famB]{%
      g[id=b1]{b1}
      union[id=famX]{%
        p[id=b2]{b2}
        c[id=b3]{b3}
      }
      union[id=famBa]{%
        p[id=ba1]{ba1}
        c[id=ba2]{ba2}
      }
        p[id=bb1]{bb1}
        child[id=famC]{%
          g[id=c1]{c1}
          p[id=c2]{c2}
          c[id=c3]{c3}
        }
    }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think @pst posted the correct answer to the primary problem, i.e. the wrong family was selected in the original code. But in my opinion, your answer shows a good alternative by rearranging the code :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks for looking. So you can highlight the connection between `b1` and `c1` for family `famBb` even though `b1` is not created within `famBb`? Is this because `b1` is the `g` node?

Comment: You could also do weird things like `x={famB}{ba2}{c1}` which would connect `ba2` with `c1`. Here, the edge would go up to reach the height of the `famB` center and then go down. The `famB` family id serves as position information, even if all connected nodes are not family members.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks for that explanation. It actually makes much more sense now. (I'm sure it is in the documentation but there is quite a lot of it, which is good, obviously, but it is sometimes hard to find things. As with the TikZ manual.)